# How to see if a Field in a MongoDB document as any matches from strings in an Array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongodb Document where I have a field like so.

```
productTitle: "Samsung 860 Evo M.2 NVME SSD"
```

And let's say that I have an array of Keywords like so.

```
['samsung', 'm.2', '860']
```

How can I query MongoDB so that if any of these keywords matches any parts of the `productTitle` then it returns that document?

Answer (score 0):

The [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#-in) query operator supports regular expressions.

You could run the above query like:

```
db.collection.find({productTitle: {$in: [/samsung/, /m\.2/, /860/]}})
```

Note that the mongod server will not be able to use indexes to support that query.

You might consider a [text index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes) to improve performance.